# Commit internal transactions while debugging JUnit tests in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, junit, spring-transactions, spring-test

I add the `@Transactional` annotation to my JUnit test class as suggested [in the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-tx).

However, the test methods are accessing multiple service methods, each being a transaction (and annotated as `@Transactional` too). Maybe these are not unit tests? anyway, I want my tests to call multiple service methods, no matter how you call them.

Internal transactions in the middle of the test are not committed to the database (because of the Test class `@Transactional` annotiation), so I can't check the DB while debugging the test after each internal transaction. However, if I remove the `@Transactional` annotation, the test breaks.

How should I configure the test so that it commits the internal transactions as they occur?

Comment: Did you try `@Commit` [more information](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#spring-testing-annotation-commit)? Otherwise please provide your test source code with test configuration.

Answer (score 1):

With Spring Framework 3.2.x you can use `@Rollback(false)` to instruct the *Spring TestContext Framework* to **commit** the transaction for your integration test.

Beginning with Spring Framework 4.2 you can use `@Commit` to achieve the same goal.